# How to improve the precision of this approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, numerical-calculus

I have to approximate $\pi$ by using 
$\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n$
with
$z_2=2, z_{n+1}=2^{n-1/2}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-4^{1-n}z_{n}^2}}, n=2,3,...$

How can I improve the accuracy of this approximation when calculating the iterations in Matlab? $z_{n+1}=0$ for $n>30$, I assume its because of the squareroot getting too close to $0$, is that correct? How can I modify this equation to reach better results when using a computer?
Any help is very much appreciated (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: You may try $$
z_{n + 1}  = \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{{\sqrt {1 + \sqrt {1 - 4^{1 - n} z_n^2 } } }}z_n .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You need not worry about you English, your question is very clear. If you want to be fanatical about it, then "precision" is used to denote the accuracy of the basic arithmetic operations, i.e., addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, while accuracy is more general and can be applied to any result. This is a distinction which is applied mainly within the field of numerical analysis.

Comment: This is a delightful iteration. Would you add a few words about it origin?

Comment: @CarlChristian If you symbolically work out the first few iterations, there should be a lot of cancellation. I would expect it's related either to some nested radical but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I believe you. I am hoping that there is beautiful geometrical background which can be easily transmitted as a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, the issue is the cancellation which occurs within the first radical. This may be handled by rationalizing it:

$$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-4^{1-n}z_n^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-(1-4^{1-n}z_n^2)}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-4^{1-n}z_n^2}}}=\frac{2^{1-n}|z_n|}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-4^{1-n}z_n^2}}}$$

Multiplying by $2^{n-1/2}$ and noting $z_n\ge0$ leaves

$$z_{n+1}=\frac{z_n\sqrt2}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-4^{1-n}z_n^2}}}$$